# Is a closed-form expression of this non-linear expression attainable?

Tags: sequences-and-series

A sequence is defined by:
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}$$
With $a_1=1$

Is a closed-form expression for this sequence possible? A search turns up the rule that all expressions with linear recurrence and constant coefficients will definitely have a closed-form representation. But this is not a linear expression, since i's definition includes the reciprocal of the previous term.

If it *is* possible, what could it be?

Comment: [WA](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%28n%2B1%29%3Da%28n%29+%2B1%2Fa%28n%29%2C+a%281%29%3D1&x=0&y=0) doesn't find a closed down.

Comment: I cannot provide evidence, but I seriously doubt there is a close form expression for this.

Comment: If you interpret $a_n$ as a continued fraction then $a_{n + 1}$ is the sum of two continued fractions of known coefficients. So it may just be possible to find a closed form using continued fraction arithmetic, but I doubt it. Maybe someone knows a trick for this one though.